# File upload works in Thunder Client and Chrome, but not Dio or MultipartRequest

Tags: flutter, form-data, deno, dio, supabase

I'm trying to create a flutter app that will allow a user to upload an image and a brief description of said image, and if I test my server code with either Thunder Client or Chrome, it works great, but if I try either the MultipartRequest or Dio from a Flutter app, the image seems to be included in the list of text fields, and the "files" part of the `form` object is empty. This happens no matter whether I try to upload an image or a small text document. Here is my Flutter code:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text("Submit Report"),
  onPressed: () async {
    var dio = Dio();
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "description": "This is a description",
      "location": "This is a location",
      "image": MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          utf8.encode("hello, world"),
          filename: "hello.txt",
          contentType: MediaType("text", "plain")),
    });

    var response = await dio.post(
      "${dotenv.env['SUPABASE_FUNCTIONS_URL']!}/hello-world",
      data: formData,
    );

    debugPrint("***${response.statusCode}***");
  },
)
```

If I debug and look at the Network tab in Dart's DevTools, I can see the request headers are set like they should be (`Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data` and a boundary is set). My server is just a small Deno function using the multiParser library running on Supabase:

```
serve(async (req) => {
  const form = await multiParser(req);
  console.log(form);

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify(form),
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } },
  );
})
```

If I look at the invocation logs on Supabase, the requests coming from Thunder Client and Chrome look fine; the fields and files are populated the way they should be. Meanwhile, coming from Flutter (Dio and MultipartRequest yield the same result), the `console.log(form)` from above looks like this:

```
{
  fields: {
    description: "This is a description",
    location: "This is a location",
    'image"; filename="hello.txt"\r\ncontent-type: text/plai': "hello, world"
  },
  files: {}
}
```

I have tried manually setting various headers (like `Content-Type`), tried both the MultipartRequest and Dio approaches, and tried manually tweaking the file being uploaded (content type as well as file body). Also tried both running in an emulator as well as on a real Android phone. The result is always the same.

Comment: you need `'files': [MultipartFile.fromBytes ...]` and not `'image: MultipartFile.fromBytes ...`

Comment: Hi @pskink, thank you for responding, but unfortunately that won't work; that'll just cause a "files" item to appear in `fields` (just to be thorough, I tested). If it worked the way it was intended, there would be an `image` item under `files`. I can also confirm that an equivalent request works from cURL. The mixture of single- and double-quotes in the `image` field in my original post is not due to my error, as far as I can tell. I'm beginning to think the MultipartRequest class is just buggy, and I may have to roll my own.

Comment: Thanks again, @pskink, and I'm not sure what we're doing differently, but I've tried all of those approaches (and re-tried them before typing this comment), but for some reason, I think what's happening is that the contents of the file (including the metadata/headers) are being always treated like a normal form-data field, instead of being treated like an attached file. No idea why this only seems to happen with Flutter code.

Comment: set a breakpoint here https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/form_data.dart#L47 and debug your app, does it go to `files.add(...` or `fields.add(...`?

Comment: Yes. I am using `formData.files.add`, and the debugger does pause at that location.

Comment: and where does it go if you "step over" that `if` at line #48?

Comment: It moves onto the `var response = ...`. I did some further inspecting with pretty_dio_logger, and it seems that Dio is not setting the Content-Type header properly; it still says application/json. I can't manually set it to multipart/form-data because I don't know what the boundary will be ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Used Oak's multipart/form-data parser instead, and it works with everything. Seems to be some sort of incompatibility between MultipartRequest/Dio and multiParser. Thanks to @pskink for troubleshooting with me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).